# How do I adjust column widths in a single choice matrix in Qualtrics?

Tags: css, matrix, qualtrics

I'm looking for the CSS to adjust column widths in a single choice 10-point matrix table in Qualtrics. I'd like to make all columns the same width, but I have 2 achor labels that are throwing off the widths.

Comment: Please provide more detail about what it is you are trying to achieve and what you've already tried.

Answer (score 1):

Use labels for the anchor labels instead of including them in the scale points. No CSS needed.